# "planning the" vs. "planning of"; "producing the" vs. "producing of"

Tags: grammar, gerunds

I cannot find an explanation for the use of gerund + *of,* such as:

- planning *of* our future vacation;
- producing *of* sound; etc.,

—versus the same without *of.*

I prefer without *of.*

Which is correct?

Comment: *of* is not mandatory in such cases, it can be elided without grammatical error. However, the definite article is not a substitute for the preposition here as is implied by the title of this post. By the way, where is the *the* in the example in the body of the question?

Comment: I understand the definite article is not a substitute. I was not sure how to stress that in the first case it is the accusative which follows while the latter one it is the genitive. When saying it is not "mandatory" I would appreciate to know when it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In answering your question it is helpful to start with an extract from the definition of *gerund* in *The Oxford Dictionary of English Grammar* (p178):

> The noun-like and verb-like properties of the *-ing* form are on a
> cline.

Nouns are not followed by direct objects, so we cannot say:

> *The planning my vacation (took a lot of time)

since *planning* in this case clearly functions as a noun by virtue of the inclusion of the determiner *the*. It needs to be followed by a prepositional complement:

> The planning of my vacation (took a lot of time).

However, in the phrase:

> Planning my vacation (took a lot of time).

*planning* takes on verb-like qualities, and hence can indeed be followed by a direct object. And of course verbs can be modified by adverbs, so you can say:

> Carefully planning my vacation (took a lot of time).

---

In answer to OP's follow-on question in the comment: The definite article is typically used in front of a noun that is followed by a prepositional complement starting with *of*:

> The cost of my vacation was very low.
>
> *Cost of my vacation was very low.
>
> The planning of my vacation took a long time.
>
> *Planning of my vacation took a long time.

--

There is a similar question [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/58119/the-x-ing-of-y-vs-just-x-ing-y-why-are-both-the-and-of-necessary-toget), with a much greater discussion of the relevant issues.