# Can I really follow the theoretical framework proposed in the Cambridge Grammar of the English Language?

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis, linguistics, category, constituents

In the book 'the Cambridge Grammar of the English Language (CGEL)', the authors propose the theoretical framework used to describe the English sentences as shown below:

[image]

Text version:

> Clause:
>
> - Subject: NP
>
>   - Det: D → *a*
>   - Head: N → *bird*
> - Predicate: VP
>
>   - Predicator: V → *hit*
>   - Object: NP
>
>     - Det: D → *the*
>     - Head: N → *car*

*CGEL, page 26*

To get the tree diagram above, the first step is to identify the constituents of the sentence with the constituency tests. The second step is to describe these constituents what grammatical categories (e.g.,N, D, NP) they belong to. And the last step is to further describe these constituents what grammatical functions (e.g. object, head, subject) they belong to.

The authors suggest I have to know what grammatical categories these constituents belong to before knowing what grammatical functions they belong to. However, when I try to follow this order, there seem to be some problems.

For example, I want to know what grammatical category the word 'dog' in the sentence 'the dog is smiling' belongs to. I suspect it might be a noun, so I turn to page 326 of the book where the properties of nouns are described. One of the properties of nouns is that it functions as 'head' of the noun phrase. My problem is: How am I supposed to know the grammatical function of the word 'dog' when the authors suggest that I first have to know its grammatical categories before knowing its grammatical functions?

> Summary of defining properties of nouns
>
> | [Type] | [Description] |
> | --- | --- |
> | i INFLECTION | Nouns prototypically inflect for number (singular vs plural) and for case (plain vs genitive). |
> | ii FUNCTION | Nouns characteristically function as head in NP structure. |
> | iii DEPENDENTS | Various dependents occur exclusively or almost exclusively with nouns as head: certain determinatives (***a** book, **every** day*), pre-head AdjPs (***good** news*), relative clauses (*people **who work***). Conversely, nouns differ from verbs and prepositions in that they do not take objects: *I dislike **it*** but not **my dislike **it***. |

*CGEL, page 326*

([image of the quote above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ln6fl.png))

Comment: Out of the many, many different properties of nouns listed, you are focussing only on one, which is that nouns *may* head phrases functioning as Subject. Fulfilling just ***one*** potential property of nouns is not sufficient to tell you anything! the fact that *dog* happens to be functioning as Head of a phrase functioning as Subject just tells you that it *might* be a noun. You need to look at all the other properties that nouns typically possess. There is no single property of nouns that it sufficient on its own to guarantee membership of the category *Noun*. (cont)

Comment: You might find [this post helpful or interesting: *How can I Prove a Word is a Noun?*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/229194/how-can-i-prove-a-word-is-a-noun/229218#229218). You could also look at the [case study there: *weekdays*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/229194/how-can-i-prove-a-word-is-a-noun/229888#229888).

Comment: Oh, and you can't not follow the grammar proposed in CaGEL. Not until there is another grammar of similar scope depth and consistency. It is widely regarded as the most comprehensive, consistent and up-to-date grammar of English there is - even by its opponents!

Comment: So the take away points: 1) Many types of word or phrase can fulfil a given syntactic function. 2) A type of phrase or word category may fulfil many types of syntactic function. 3)Knowing the word category is not sufficient to determine  the syntactic function of that word or the phrase it heads. 4) Knowing a word or phrase's syntactic function is not sufficient to tell you its phrasal category or word category.

Comment: Thank you so much for your valuable insight! I've learned a lot.

Comment: So does that mean even if I do not know the grammatical function of the word 'dog,' I can look at other properties, which are as important, to determine whether or not it is a noun, right?

Comment: Spot on. Exactly so!

Comment: I've edited your title because your question hasn't been getting many views. I think these changes may increase the chances of your getting a good answer! However, if you don't like them, you can roll them back by clicking on the "edited" button just to the left of where your name appears and then clicking on "roll back"".

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. Haven't you written an answer here?

Comment: @Araucaria I appreciate your works a lot!

Comment: I think you're looking at this the wrong way. You don't use he sentence grammar to understand the sentence. First you determine what the sentence (and by extension all the words in it) means because you know the language. From that you can assign the words to categories.

Comment: English (and most human languages) is too complex to parse purely syntactically. This was something discovered very early on by AI reasearchers on natural language processing.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you!

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. Sorry for tagging you again as it is the only way to contact you through this site. I have a question regarding the *weekdays* case study. Thanks to it I learn how to actually apply those grammatical properties in the CGEL book to words I encounter. However, I just want to know that when you conclude in the end that *weekdays* is a noun, you mean it is a noun in that particular instance, i.e. in the sentence *It's open weekdays* only, right? So if I encounter the word *weekdays* in another sentence I have to apply those properties again. Do I understand it correctly?

Comment: @Mz2501 In principle, yes. You might, for example, be looking at a homophone. For example, *round* is famous for potentially being one of many different word categories. However, it depends why you're doing it! A coupe of strong bits of evidence is often all you need. For example, if it occurs (or could) with a determiner such as *a* or *every* and has a singular and plural form, then you can be confident it's a noun!

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. Got it! I have to thank you again for taking your time to give me valuable information.

Comment: @Mz2501 You're very welcome!